# Outlook VSTO TypeText("text") Throws "The TypeText method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing" Exception

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

Calling `TypeText("dummytext")` on `ActiveInspector` WordEditor throws:

**The TypeText method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing.**

Here is my code:

```
var inspector = myMailItem.GetInspector;
dynamic w = inspector.WordEditor;
dynamic wa = w.Application;
wa.Selection.TypeText("sometext");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen lots of issues if using selection this way.  This is how I would do it

```
object link = url;
object res = "url";
object missing = Type.Missing;

// get active inspector (note that this assumes you work always on the active email message).
var inspector = ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
MailItem email = inspector.CurrentItem;  // get the email message 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = email.GetInspector.WordEditor;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection sel = document.Windows[1].Selection;
doc.Hyperlinks.Add(sel.Range, ref res, ref missing, ref missing, ref link, ref missing);
sel.EndKey(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdLine);  // move to the end of selection
sel.InsertAfter("\n");  // insert new line
sel.MoveDown(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdLine);  // move one line down
```