# Outlook VSTO - Calling TypeText on Selection throws "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" Exception

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Calling `Selection.TypeText("sometext")` throws:

"**Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference**" error

[image]

Comment: That means the Selection variable is null.

Comment: I know but I am trying to figure out why it is null sometimes while othertimes it is not or I get different errors like (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982358/outlook-vsto-calling-typetext-on-selection-throws-this-command-is-not-availab, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964834/outlook-vsto-typetexttext-throws-the-typetext-method-or-property-is-not-ava, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982131/outlook-vsto-calling-typetext-on-selection-throws-cannot-perform-runtime-bind).  Thanks Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming you got selection object in your code but you have not.  I also saw your other posts about same topic (TypeText) and they although showing different errors are all coming from the same problem.  The code is either not getting selection at all, or it is getting wrong selection (to which you cannot call TypeText).  For example, I have seen this where you select one email in email list (without opening it), then you open a new email message.

Unfortunately, MS documentation/MSDN is constantly deteriorating over the last few years and there is very little help out there on this topic, so I posted my answer how to do this here [Outlook VSTO - Calling TypeText on Selection throws "This command is not available" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982358/outlook-vsto-calling-typetext-on-selection-throws-this-command-is-not-availab)

Hope that helps.