# Outlook VSTO - Calling TypeText on Selection throws "This command is not available" Exception

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Calling `TypeText` on `Selection` throws "This command is not available." exception

[image]

Below is my code

```
public void AddFilePaths(List<string> urls)
{
    if (urls.Count > 0)
    {
        MailItem mi = null;
        bool newMailItem = false;

        mi = MyAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mi.Body = "New email body"; 
        newMailItem = true;

        mi.Display();
        inspector = MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();

        if (mi != null)
        {
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                AddPathToActiveInspector(urls);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void AddLinkToCurrentInspector(string url)
{
    var inspector = MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
    var currMessage = inspector.CurrentItem;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document word = currMessage.GetInspector.WordEditor; 
    dynamic wordapp = word.Application;
    const string text = "\n"; // thisfor some reason will not add new line
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection sel = word.Windows[1].Selection;
    sel.TypeText(text); // this often errors
    string address = url;
    string subAddress = "";
    string screenTip = "";
    string textToDisplay = url; 
    wordapp.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(sel.Range, ref address, ref subAddress, ref screenTip, ref textToDisplay);
    if (word.ProtectionType != Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection) word.Unprotect(); 
    sel.TypeText(" "); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on answer in this question, I also resolved this issue.  The code that works better than code above and is more easy to follow is below.  Many thanks to @joeshwa:

```
    public void AddLinkToCurrentInspector(string url)
    {
        object link = url;
        object result = "url";
        object missing = Type.Missing;

        var inspector = MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
        MailItem currMessage = inspector.CurrentItem;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = currMessage.GetInspector.WordEditor;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection sel = doc.Windows[1].Selection;
        doc.Hyperlinks.Add(sel.Range, ref result, ref missing, ref missing, ref link, ref missing);
        sel.EndKey(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdLine);
        sel.InsertAfter("\n");
        sel.MoveDown(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdLine);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `TypeText` - just set the Text property:

```
Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Text = "test"
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, that makes no difference.  Thanks Dmitry

Comment: Are you calling this on an inspector in the edit mode? Or is it a read-only inspector?

Comment: I updated my post to include code.  Thank you Dmitry

Comment: Why are you using MailItem.GetInspector if you already have the Inspector object? Also do not use Window.Selection - use Application.Selection.

Comment: If you look at the screenshot I posted, I was using Application.Selection (see above in screenshot wordapp.Selection).  Same for MailItem.GetInspector.  If you look at the screenshot, you will see that I have used existing Inspector object from ActiveInspector.  So, I am not sure what do you mean but that actually was source of all problems.  The code I updated actually is working.  Much appreciated Dmitry.  BTW, how do I set inspector to always be in edit mode?  Much appreciated

Comment: Looks at the line "word = currMessage.GetInspector.WordEditor". You are using GetInspector. There is no need - you can use the value from 'MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector'

Comment: I know, but that is the code that actually works Dmitry :).  If you look at the screenshot I posted originally, you will see that I was using "MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector" and that was causing bunch of issues for me.  In debug mode especially where I would see it crash on line that calls Selection.TypeText("text") (or Selection.Text = "text", or Selection.InsertAfter("text")).